# Multilevel dataframe from file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file looking where every nth row (here every fourth row) is a header and the first element of the other rows are also headers.

data.txt

```
12
1  3  2
2  9  8
3  3  2
32
1  3  8
2  4  8
3  4  3
82
1  0  4
2  3  2
3  1  1
```

which I want to convert to a two-level dataframe, preferably using pandas.

dataframe in Python

```
      0  1
12 1  3  2
   2  9  8
   3  3  2
32 1  3  8
   2  4  8
   3  4  3
82 1  0  4
   2  3  2
   3  1  1
```

What's a good way to achieve this?

---

As requested, here is `df.to_dict()` using pprint

```py
{0: {(12, 1): 3,
     (12, 2): 9,
     (12, 3): 3,
     (32, 1): 3,
     (32, 2): 4,
     (32, 3): 4,
     (82, 1): 0,
     (82, 2): 3,
     (82, 3): 1},
 1: {(12, 1): 2,
     (12, 2): 8,
     (12, 3): 2,
     (32, 1): 8,
     (32, 2): 8,
     (32, 3): 3,
     (82, 1): 4,
     (82, 2): 2,
     (82, 3): 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the file manually:

```
import csv

idx1 = []
idx2 = []
index1 = 0

data = []

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, dialect='excel', delimiter=' ',skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        row = [int(i) for i in row]
        if len(row) == 1:
            index1 = row[0]
        else:
            idx1.append(index1)
            idx2.append(row[0])
            data.append(row[1:])

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx1, idx2])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx)
```

This works even with different sizes per group.

Answer (score 1):

You can can read the *.txt* file twice and leverage on `skiprows` parameter in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) which takes a function as a parameter.

```
#setup
from io import StringIO
text = """12
1  3  2
2  9  8
3  3  2
32
1  3  8
2  4  8
3  4  3
82
1  0  4
2  3  2
3  1  1"""
```

Replace `StringIO(text)` with `filename.txt`

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),
                 sep='\s+', 
                 header=None, 
                 skiprows=lambda x: (not x%4), index_col=0
                 )
# Skipping every 4th row.
df
#   1  2
#0
#1  3  2
#2  9  8
#3  3  2
#1  3  8
#2  4  8
#3  4  3
#1  0  4
#2  3  2
#3  1  1

# Now, read every 4th row.
idx = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text),
                  sep='\s+', 
                  header=None, 
                  skiprows=lambda x: (x%4), 
                  usecols=[0], squeeze=True
                  )
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(idx.repeat(3), df.index)) #repeat has to be n-1
```

Output:

```
df
      1  2
12 1  3  2
   2  9  8
   3  3  2
32 1  3  8
   2  4  8
   3  4  3
82 1  0  4
   2  3  2
   3  1  1

# df now has MultiIndex
df.index
MultiIndex([(12, 1),
            (12, 2),
            (12, 3),
            (32, 1),
            (32, 2),
            (32, 3),
            (82, 1),
            (82, 2),
            (82, 3)],
           )
```

Checking for correctness

```
from pandas._tesing import asser_frame_equal

benchmark = pd.DataFrame({0: {(12, 1): 3,
     (12, 2): 9,
     (12, 3): 3,
     (32, 1): 3,
     (32, 2): 4,
     (32, 3): 4,
     (82, 1): 0,
     (82, 2): 3,
     (82, 3): 1},
 1: {(12, 1): 2,
     (12, 2): 8,
     (12, 3): 2,
     (32, 1): 8,
     (32, 2): 8,
     (32, 3): 3,
     (82, 1): 4,
     (82, 2): 2,
     (82, 3): 1}})

assert_frame_equal(df,benchmark)
#DataFrame.columns values are different (100.0 %)
#[left]:  Int64Index([1, 2], dtype='int64')
#[right]: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')

# Error raised as your benchmark DataFrame has columns [0, 1], my answer has [1, 2]
# This can be fixed by adjusting your columns suitably

df.columns = [0, 1]
assert_frame_equal(df,benchmark) # No AssertionError raised
```